# parse html page

Tags: android, html-parsing

i want to parse 1 url and afterwords i want to access some data from that.

```
try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://abc.com/en/currency/default.aspx").get();//abc is for example as i cant put site name
        Elements td = doc.select("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_currencylist_rptCurrencyList_ctl01_trList"); //this is the name of table row in html page i will show html page snippet also
        String temp=td.val();
        info.setText(temp);
    } 
     catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

snippet of html page which i want to parse is as follows

```
       <tr id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_currencylist_rptCurrencyList_ctl01_trList">
<td width="400px" class="CurrencyListItems">             
         UK POUND
         </td>
<td width="60px;" class="CurrencyListItemsIN" align="center">
         5.72
         </td>
<td width="150px;" class="CurrencyListItemsLast">
           <table cellspacing ="0" cellpadding ="0" width="100%">
                   <tr>
                     <td class="CurrencyListBANKNOTES" align="center">                         
                     5.625
                     </td>
                     <td class="CurrencyListBANKNOTES2" width="75px" align="center">

                     5.75
                     </td>
                   </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
```

i want from above html UK pound ,5.625,5.75
i tried above code,but the thng is it is not parsing URL only its jus coming out if try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
Element tr = doc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_currencylist_rptCurrencyList_ctl01_trList");
```

try

```
String contents = tr.text().trim();
contents = contents.replaceAll("\\s+"," "); 
contents = contents. replaceAll("\\<.*?>","-");
String []values = contents.split("-");
```

or

```
Elements elements = tr.select("*");
for (Element element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.ownText());
}
```

Comment: @Nammari-ur earlier solution wrked perfectly,jus the thng is tat split dnt wrkd so inside values array whole 4 items came but tats not a prob this upvoting was for tat ans.thnx v much..

Comment: @Nammari-thi new updated ans u put in tat it is gvng errot on
    for (Element element : elements)  as elements not found..

Comment: @ Nammari-hey thnx alot..it worked i gt wat was the mmistake instead of elments in for loop it should be allElementInTr..